# Identity Server 4 reference token and security

Tags: .net-core, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

In my project I use the identity server 4, an SPA (Angular) and a protected API (PHP). I decided me to use the reference token. My Client (SPA) works with implicit flow (is it correct not to use a client secret?) And gets the access token after login (call the authorize endpoint). After that the SPA have to send the token to the API so the API can ask the identity server 4 (introspection endpoint), if the access token is correct and the API can get access to the user´s information.

Now I want to know, how to secure the communication. Because the access token has no information in it, is it necessary to send him with jwt to the API or is it enough with a normal JSON send? As I understand the API must call the introspection endpoint with jwt bearer.

Is this method secure or what else should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such requirement - the API to call the introspection with a JWT. If the API is set to work with JWT's it will just verify the signature of the token with the public key from IDS. If it is set to work with reference token - it will call the introspection, to get the user info (which is the payload of the JWT). [Reference tokens documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html).

Your API needs to be protected with its ID and Secret, so that you can call the introspection endpoint.

When calling it you send the reference token (it is still an access token, but it is not a JWT), the `client_id` and the `client_secret`. The content-type of the request should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it should be POST.

The response from the introspection endpoint is the user info.

No need of additional security - the client ID and Secret are the security, and the call is made server-to-server from API to IDS (assuming you are behind `https` of course)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the thing is that i have no client_secret because a SPA can´t hold the secret. (at least that's what I read). One more question: After the IDS accept the call of introspection point the api should send the answeer to the client with jwt or is that not necessary? at the moment i send only json between client and api

Comment: Sorry may be I didn't express myself correctly - by client_id and secret I meant the ones for the API. Regarding your question - the API needs the response from the introspection to validate the user identity (claims etc). No need to send this info back to the client (except if you don't need id for some specific logic)

Comment: ah all right thank you. and the response from the API to the client (if the client want some data from the API and not the call to the IDS) should be jwt to secure the data?